# Выдача заказов (вопрос по алгоритму)

Tags: алгоритм

Всем привет. Вопрос по алгоритму.

Есть база заказов, в ней содержится адрес получателя и количество желаемых открыток.
Пример записи из базы: ул. Ленина дом1, 100 открыток.
Человек, что делает заказ хочет получить различные(!) открытки. То есть чтобы от одного человека была только одна открытка. Если он заказал 100 открыток, то он хочет получить 100 разных(!) открыток.

Есть люди, которые отправляют открытки, им показываются эти самые заказы. Одному почтальону (будем их так называть) показывается один заказ от одного человека (чтобы все пришедшие открытки были разные).

Вопрос теперь в том, как выдавать эти заказы? Чтобы заказчики получили как можно быстрее свои открытки?

Почтальонов много, заказов тоже. Бывает почтальонов меньше чем заказов, бывает наоборот.
Пример базы (список отсортирован по убыванию, по дате заказа. То есть внизу те, кто заказал раньше. Вверху те кто заказал совсем недавно.)

> ул. Ленина дом1, 100 открыток.
>
> ул. Петрова дом14, 10 открыток.
>
> ул. Ломоносова дом20, 300 открыток.
>
> ул. Иванова дом187, 50 открыток.

Варианты:

1. По очереди. То есть кто раньше заказал, тот заказ первым и выдаем. И все почтальоны выполняют сначала первый заказ. Минус этого подхода в том, что верхний заказ начнет выполнятся только тогда, когда выполнятся предыдущие, то есть верхний будет долго ждать открытки.
2. Выдавать в порядке общей очереди. То есть например у нас 4 заказа и 4 почтальона. Первый заказ берет первый почтальон, второй заказ берет второй почтальон, и т.д. Что-то типа многозадачности. Есть ли тут какие-то минусы?

Для отправителя 1 заказ можно обработать 1 раз. Если он отправил открытку по этому заказу, больше этот заказ ему показывать не надо! Иначе получатель получит еще одну открытку от этого отправителя. А он хочет получить открытки от разных отправителей.

Как лучше организовать выдачу, чтобы заказчики получили свои открытки как можно быстрее?

Спасибо.

Comment: Полное ощущение, что в задаче не хватает условий.

С точки зрения здравой логики, конечно второй вариант, но как-то сильно просто.

Comment: А какой ресурс почтальона? т.е. на один заказ может прийти один почтальон? Ну и т.д.... У Вас т.е. есть очередь получателей, очередь производителей и очередь доставки. Как строится очередь производителей?

Comment: Ресурс? Ну пока ему не надоест отправлять :)
Почтальон отрабатывает и уходит. В это время приходят другие. Но всегда есть какое-то количество работающих почтальонов. Количество работающих почтальонов может меняться (как захотят, так начнут отправлять).
Почтальон отрабатывает один заказ (1 открытку) идет дальше к другому заказу и т.д., пока ему не надоест. На каждый заказ он отправит 1 открытку.
Отправители (почтальоны) это не совсем очередь. Это группа работающих в данный момент людей. Контролировать это кол-во не получится. Т.е. захочет будет отправлять, нет так нет.

Comment: Т.е. почтальон может отправить только одну открытку заказчику?

Comment: Да. Заказчик хочет открытки от разных отправителей. То есть если он заказал 500 открыток, то он хочет получить их от 500 разных почтальонов.

Comment: Используйте сервис http://www.rabbitmq.com/ его можно настраивать под все удобства.